# PSR-4 autoloading with Composer

Tags: php, composer-php, autoload, psr-4

I run a portail with composer's autoloading class system:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Portal\\": "src/"
    }
}
```

It works when I run `composer.phar dump -o`, for instance my class Boostrap is well referenced into `vendor/composer/autoload_classmap.php` file:

```
'Portal\\Core\\Bootstrap' => $baseDir . '/src/core/Bootstrap.php',
```

But when I don't run the *optimized* option on autoload dumping, the autoloading system doesn't works anymore:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Portal\Core\Bootstrap' not found in /var/www/portail/prod/web/index.php on line 7
```

How can I make autoloading works without `-o` option?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There are two ways to fix it.

1. change `composer.json` to

   ```
   "Portal\\Core\\": "src/core/"
   ```
2. Or rename the `core` directory to `Core`

https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#psr-4

> The subdirectory name MUST match the case of the sub-namespace names.

http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/