# PHP : Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'abc\abc' not found in demo.php

Tags: php, composer-php

I installed composer and initiate in my project folder.
so after installed that /vendor folder created in my project directory by composer.

after that i created two file 
1.abc.php 
2.demo.php

in abc.php my code is:

```
namespace abc;
class abc
{
    public function pm()
    {
    echo "test";
    }
}
```

and my demo.php file code is :

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';
use abc\abc;
$abc = new abc();
```

I just want to access pm() method of 'abc' class using 'namespace' and 'use' method  without using this require_once 'abc.php'.

But i getting below error while call demo.php.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'abc\abc' not found in /opt/lampp/htdocs/mycomposer/demo.php:8

My File path : opt/lampp/htdocs/php/mycomposer/demo.php
opt/lampp/htdocs/php/mycomposer/abc.php
opt/lampp/htdocs/php/mycomposer/vendor
```

Any idea please share. Thanks

Comment: Composer does not know about your manually created files.

Comment: You need to add your own autoloader for your classes or just include them one by one

Comment: so composer autoload file is not handle this , am i right ?

Comment: or use some frameworks that autoload them automaticaly like `laravel` or `symfony`

Comment: Composer handles this when you tell it how to include your files.

Comment: Can you add your `composer.json` file and also the the directory structure for you site i.e. where is your `abc.php` file and where is your `demo.php` file?

Comment: so all my class file need to include?

Comment: Start with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28607674/psr-4-autoloading-with-composer

Comment: i added file path in question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can edit your compose.json file and add following

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "abc\\": "",
        }
    }
}
```

do

```
composer update
```

and test

check https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#psr-4 for more details

Comment: thanks for your answer. can you tell why this need to add in composer.json? because if we see in some framework like laravel , magento then its not need to add your custom file class in composer.json.

Comment: if u look at composer.json in laravel you see they already have "psr-4": { "": "src/" } declaration in their composer.json to map namespace to path.

Answer (score -1):

You should use require_once to include the files where the class abc resides, and if you succeed, you need to take a closer look at how autoload.php works.

Comment: Hi @toby, thank you for your contribution. however OP is using composer to handle class auto-loading. this is a nice technology to make live easier™. see the [QA posted by u_mulder regarding PSR-4 and Composer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28607674/psr-4-autoloading-with-composer).

Comment: PSR-4 is not a framework in sense like symfony or Code Igniter, but its a standard (recommendation), see [here](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/).